# How to migrate to new google identity service sign in?

Tags: html, reactjs, google-identity

I have an app where I need to migrate to the new google identity service sign in methods. For several days I am stuck on this issue and I have no idea how to do it, the documentation that google provides seems really confusing for me, so I came here to ask for the help.

My current sign in consists of several parts:

1. The html file:

   ```
   <html lang="en" class="clicking">
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
       <title><%= title %></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app<%= version %>.css?"/>
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico"/>
       <% include partials/_hotjar.ejs %>
       <% include partials/_googleAnalytics.ejs %>
   </head>
   <body id="account">
   <% include partials/_googleTagManagerNoScript.ejs %>

   <% include partials/header.ejs %>

   <div id="application"></div>

   <% include partials/footer.ejs %>
   <script src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
   <script type="application/javascript">
       window.ENVIRONMENT = '<%= process.env.NODE_ENV %>';
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app<%= version %>.js"></script>
   <script type="application/javascript">
       APP.init();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

I guess here I need to include the new script file that google provides?

2. The app.jsx file:

   ```
       gapi.load('auth2', () => gapi.auth2.init({
           client_id: Config.googlePlus.clientId,
       }));
   ```

What do I need to update here, as you can see I am using the `gapi` method, but what would be the new one, I do not get from the library.

3. The login component:

   let auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
   auth2.grantOfflineAccess({redirect_uri: 'postmessage'})

What would be the replacement from the new method?

If you can help me with this, I would gladly appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you clear what google changed? Because before I write answers it's very important that you know what the difference between new and old. If not please see this list first https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#library_quick_reference

Comment: I have read the whole documentation, the only thing I get is that the authentication and authorization are now seperated, and that I need to change my function with new ones, or to remove some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process has three steps

**Step 1: Load script**

Include this script `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`

**Step 2: Initiate a client**

When user clicks the `Sign in with google` button you have to initiate the client using

```
const client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient(params);
```

Here the params are

```js
{
    client_id: <your_client_id>,
    callback: <success_callback_function>,
    scope: <your_auth_scopes>,
    error_callback: <error_callback_function>,
}
```

**Step 3: Request token using the client**

After the client is loaded request for access token

```
client.requestAccessToken();
```

**All together**

```js
const handleSuccessResponse = (response) => {
  console.log(response.access_token)
}

const handleErrorResponse = (response) => {
  console.log(response)
}

const signInWithGoogle = () => {
  // create params
  const params = {
    client_id: <your_client_id>,
    callback: handleSuccessResponse,
    scope: <your_auth_scopes>,
    error_callback: handleErrorResponse,
  }
  
  // create client
  const client = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient(params);
  
  // Request token
  client.requestAccessToken();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I just have few questions. How do I render the sign in with google button?, also where do I put these functions in which component, in login or some where else?

Comment: Create a button of your own. The button onclick should trigger `signInWithGoogle` function. Where you keep it doesn't matter.

Comment: I do not have any scopes or atleast I do not understand what do they represent, do you have any example how should they look like?

Comment: Scopes are the string that tells the authentication that what you can do using the token. Suppose you want to fetch user's contact then you have to use "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.other.readonly" in the scope. Please read the doc I shared everything is explained their. If you are using it for user login then scope can be ignored. No need to add scope in the params